# transfer the object from servlet to jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am beginner,i uses jsp servlet with hibernate,I want to transfer the object from servlet to jsp

Basically I want to output the current Faculty and their respective names with the id.

here is my prog:

```
package com.college;

import com.college.faculty.Faculty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class FacultyExtract extends HttpServlet {



SessionFactory factory;
public void init(ServletConfig config ) throws ServletException
{
factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
System.out.println("Factory has been created");
}

public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
{
//HttpSession obses = request.getSession();
int pageIndex=0;
int totalNumberOfRecords=0;
int numberOfRecordsPerPage=4;

String sPageIndex= request.getParameter("pageIndex");

if(sPageIndex==null)
{

pageIndex=1;

}
else
{
pageIndex = Integer.parseInt(sPageIndex);
}

Session ses = factory.openSession();
int s= ( pageIndex*numberOfRecordsPerPage)-numberOfRecordsPerPage;

Criteria crit = ses.createCriteria(Faculty.class);
crit.setFirstResult(s);
crit.setMaxResults(numberOfRecordsPerPage);

List l= crit.list();
Iterator it =l.iterator();


for (int i=1;i>=6;i++)
{
        Faculty m = (Faculty)it.next();
        if( i==1 )
        {
            Faculty a1 = (Faculty) m ; 
            request.setAttribute("F1",a1);

        } 
        if( i==2 )
        {  Faculty a2 = (Faculty) m ;   
        request.setAttribute("F2",a2);
        } 
        if( i==3 )
        {  Faculty a3 = (Faculty) m ;   
        request.setAttribute("F3",a3);
        } 
        if( i==4 )
        {

            Faculty a4 = (Faculty) m ;
        request.setAttribute("F4",a4);
        } 
        if( i==5 )
        {  

            Faculty a5 = (Faculty) m ;   
                        request.setAttribute("F5",a5);
        } 
        if( i==6 )
        {  

            Faculty a6 = (Faculty) m ; 
             request.setAttribute("F6",a6);
        } 
    }

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Faculty.jsp");

dispatcher.forward(request , response);

}

}
```

Faculty.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.college.faculty.Faculty"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <% 
       //HttpSession obses=request.getSession();

        Faculty fac =(Faculty) request.getAttribute("f1");  

    //  System.out.println(fac.getExpDetail());  
        //String f2 = (String)fac.getQulification();

    %>

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <%=fac.getExpDetail()%>


</body>
</html>
```

error code:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException

type Exception report

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling          this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:5    49)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
com.college.FacultyExtract.service(FacultyExtract.java:116)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.Faculty_jsp._jspService(Faculty_jsp.java:90)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
com.college.FacultyExtract.service(FacultyExtract.java:116)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.3   logs.
```

faculty.java

```
package com.college.faculty;

public class Faculty {
private int fid;
private String fname;
private String qulification;
private String expDetail;

public void setFacQul(int fid,String fname,String qulification,String expDetail)
{
    this.fid = fid;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.qulification = qulification;
    this.expDetail = expDetail;
}

public int getFid() {
    return fid;
}
public void setFid(int fid) {
    this.fid = fid;
}
public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getQulification() {
    return qulification;
}
public void setQulification(String qulification) {
    this.qulification = qulification;
}
public String getExpDetail() {
    return expDetail;
}
public void setExpDetail(String expDetail) {
    this.expDetail = expDetail;
}




}
```

Comment: You have an error in your loop: for (int i=1;i>=6;i++) -- this will never enter because i is never >=6

Comment: Also your set of If statements is unecessary - your loop could be one line long: request.setAttribute("F"+i,(Faculty)it.next());

Answer (score 1):

You are using upper case "F1" in servlet and lowercase in jsp "f1". It must be the same. Its the best to define interface with constants for such purposes as attribute names are case sensitive.

```
//servlet    
request.setAttribute("F1",a1); //upper
//jsp
Faculty fac =(Faculty) request.getAttribute("f1");   // lower
```

And also error pointed by Si Kelly:

"You have an error in your loop: for (int i=1;i>=6;i++) -- this will never enter because i is never >=6 –  Si Kelly"

Should be for(int i=1; i.hasNext(); i++) or you will have exception, if less elements in collection than 6.